# What is the best approach to HTML markup for a heavily stylised h1 tag

Tags: seo, markup, semantic-web, heading, alt-attribute

I have a very stylised piece of content which I want to use as the `<h1>` tag on a page. I have two choices, either use complex, non semantic markup or an image. Is there any SEO benefit to either of the following approaches:

```
<h1>
    <span class="left">
        This is my <em>long</em><br>
        <small>example</small>
    </span>
    <span class="right">
        <span class="one">heading</span> text
    </span>
</h1>
```

or simply:

```
<h1><img src="/img.jpg" alt="This is my long example heading text." /></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

It’s totally fine (and often useful, and of course valid) to have an image as heading. You could even use audio or video as heading. HTML is content agnostic in that sense. However, in every case you should provide alternative text content (for user-agents that don’t support the media (e.g. search engines) and/or for users that can’t access them).

A typical example for an image as site heading would be a site logo that contains the site name (or the logo is that prominent that a name is not needed in addition). Example:

```
<h1><img src="nike-logo.png" alt="Nike Inc." /></h1>
```

It should be added in HTML (with `img`) and *not* via CSS (with `content` resp. `background`), because it’s content and not decoration.

Now, if you should use a heading or text depends on your actual case, of course. For example, if it’s a company logo, I’d use an image (→ others might want to download it and re-use it, e.g. in a presentation; image search engines might index it etc). If the heading is only some specially designed text, I’d try to provide text and style it with CSS.

Regarding your markup: As I don’t know your real content, this might not be relevant, but you are probably using the [`br` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element) in a wrong way here. You should only use `br` for meaningful line breaks (e.g. in addresses or poems). If your line break is for design only, you should use CSS instead (and `span`+`class` as hook element). Same with the [`small` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-small-element): only use it if it contains "side comments such as small print".

Comment: Your assuming the ALT tag is treated as the same weight as a text based H1.... Google prefers text based headers, thats why the CSS background and textual method is preferred - though there are negatives with this method too. There are hundreds of studies that can be found online which support this claim e.g http://robhammond.co/blog/how-google-handles-alt-text-in-h1-tags/ and many more on Google Search.

Comment: @bybe: As this question is not about Google specifically, I think "best practices" (from HTML and WCAG) are relevant/important for this question, because that‘s what search engines in general try to accomplish: rank pages without disadvantaging semantic/accessible markup. First there are web pages, then there are search engines. It might (!) be true that Google weights alternative text differently than text (for some time), but other factors might be relevant here (e.g. there might be a difference between alternative text of a photo and of a textual graphic).

Comment: I know what your saying its minor but its true you shouldn't consider alt text a true text replacement, that's my point. Also this applys to all search engines, and the fact the OP used the SEO tag within the question makes it relevant.

Comment: Ideally if you can you should avoid both indent and h1 img unless absolutely required to do so, and personally for Logos a simple `<span><img alt="our logo"></span>` is Enough because there's no need to use H1 Nike INC Img on every page, Google isn't dumb and can associate your site without bashing at the engine.

Answer (score 0):

Images are not headers and generally using `<h1><img src="" alt=""/></h1>` is bad practice, you could opt to use a `text-indent: -9999em` but this is becoming unfavourable and the best practice is just to use a H1 as intended.

The text indent method is pretty easy to do you just do something like this in the HTML/CSS:

*HTML*

`<h1><a class="headerimg" name="#">Header text for search engines</a></h1>`

*CSS*

```
.headerimg{
background:url("../img/header.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
display:block;
height:100px;
margin-top:0;
text-indent:-9999em;
width:240px;
}
```

At least with using the above method your using text for the search engines, but ultimately you need to note that images are not valid headers.

Comment: "Images are not headers" - Why not? There are several cases where an image *is* the only sensible heading, e.g. site heading = site logo (of course with appropriate `alt` value). `h1` is not restricted to text. You could even have an audio heading.

Comment: <h1><img src=""> is not preferred since your assuming the alt tag is the same as the H1.... this is not true

Comment: Accessibility and markup you should use proper text as the H1 and use the background element in the CSS.

Comment: @bybe "the alt tag is the same as the H1" What are you basing this on? Do you have a source that isn't half a decade old? Even the W3C implements their H1 as an image with an alt tag.

Comment: Additionally, Matt Cutts specifically says you should NOT use the above method: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBLvn_WkDJ4

Comment: If you have read the  first paragraph of my answer it says `but this is becoming unfavourable and the best practice is just to use a H1 as intended.` It should also be noted that the answer is intended for SEO and has nothing to do W3C validation, W3C plays little role in actual search rankings as websites with 100s to 1000s of errors can still rank. Additionally the reason why H1 ALT is `not favorable` is because of manipulation as people can set alt tags differently to what the actual header says in the image. You can find various information regarding this that is not a decade old.

Answer (score 0):

You may use image with the "alt" attribute, but, as bybe says, it will not be valid as heading.

> text-indent:-9999em;
>   It is bad practice, search engines do not like when you hide something.

**patnz** in your choice you should see at the speed your site load (very stylised piece of content vs image).

The faster way will be the best.

Comment: `text-indent:-9999em; It is bad practice, search engines do not like when you hide something.` not true, 100,000's of sites use this method with no ranking problems.

Comment: What goals do you pursuit by using text-indent:-9999em; ?

Comment: lots.......... commonly used when using CSS sprites for page speed is a prime example when you include things like logos, social icons, and lots of other images and you then use a text fallback.